# java implementation of Splay Tree and get the k-th largest number

Tags: java, algorithm, avl-tree

The first line will be an integer T, which is the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line will be two integers n and m. Then followed by n lines, each line will be one of the following cases:

- `I x`: Insert x. insert a number x.
- `A x`: Add x. increase each number in the sequence by x.
- `S x`: Subtract x. reduce each number in the sequence by x and then delete numbers which are less than m.
- `Q x`: Query x. print the k-th maximum number in this sequence.

**Input**

> The first line will be an integer T, which is the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line will be two integers n and m. Then followed by n lines, each line will be one of the following cases:

**Output:**

> For each “Query”, print the k-th maximum number in this sequence. If the length of the sequence is less than k, print “-1”. At last, print the number of elements we deleted.

I try to use the inverse order of In-order traversal to find the first (biggest) number and splay it to the root. Then I put the pointer of root to its right child (implemented in `update`).

The implementation of Splay is copied from the internet and the copyright is from Princeton Uni. (Thx)

Here is my code, and I get `RTR` runtime error. Thanks for reading.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Splay{
  private Node root;   // root of the BST
  public static int m = 0;
  public static int baseNum = 0;
  private int delNum = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    parse();
  }

  private static void parse() {
    try {
      InputReader inputReader = new InputReader(System.in);
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
      int case_num = inputReader.nextInt();
      while (case_num-- > 0) {
        Splay splay = new Splay();
        int n = inputReader.nextInt();
        m = inputReader.nextInt();
        while (n-- > 0) {
          String s = inputReader.next();
          int value = inputReader.nextInt();
          switch (s) {
            case "I":
              splay.put(value - baseNum);
              break;
            case "A":
              baseNum += value;
              break;
            case "S":
              baseNum -= value;
              splay.update();
              break;
            case "Q":
              Integer res = splay.find(value);
              System.out.println(res == null ? "-1" : res + baseNum);
              break;
              default:
                System.out.println("-1");
          }
        }
        System.out.println(splay.delNum);
      }
      inputReader.close();
      out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Error when paring");
    }
  }

  private Integer find(int k) {
    if (size(root) < k) {
      return null;
    }
    /* After call size, the size of each node has stored in itself*/

    Node curNode = root;
    while (true) {


//      if (curNode.left != null) {
////        System.out.println(" left = " + curNode.left);
//      }
//      if (curNode.right != null) {
////        System.out.println(" right = " + curNode.right + "right.size = " + curNode.right.size);
//      }


      if (curNode.right != null && k <= curNode.right.size) {
        curNode = curNode.right;
      } else {
        k -= curNode.right == null ? 1 : curNode.right.size + 1;
//        System.out.println("k = " + k);
        if (k == 0) {
          return curNode.key;
        } else {
          curNode = curNode.left;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private void update() {
    Integer integer = inOrderByStack();
    if (integer == null) {
      return;
    }
//    System.out.println("integer = " + integer);
    root = splay(root, integer);
//    System.out.println("delete " + root.key);
    delNum += size(root.left) + 1;
    root = root.right;
  }

  /*
  Do some modify to traversal right child first.
   */
  private Integer inOrderByStack() {
    int max = m - baseNum;
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
    Node current = root;
    while (current != null || !stack.isEmpty()) {
      while (current != null) {
        stack.push(current);
        current = current.right;
      }
      if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        current = stack.pop();
        if (current.key < max) {
          return current.key;
        }
        current = current.left;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  // BST helper node data type
  private class Node {
    private int key;            // key
    private int size;
    private Node left, right;   // left and right subtrees

    public int getSize() {
      return size;
    }

    public Node(int key) {
      this.key   = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "[ " + key + " ]";
    }
  }

  // return value associated with the given key
  // if no such value, return null
  public int get(int key) {
    root = splay(root, key);
    int cmp = Integer.compare(key, root.key);
    if (cmp == 0) return root.key;
    else          return -1;
  }

  /***************************************************************************
   *  Splay tree insertion.
   ***************************************************************************/
  public void put(int key) {
    // splay key to root
    if (root == null) {
      root = new Node(key);
      return;
    }

    root = splay(root, key);

    int cmp = Integer.compare(key, root.key);
    // Insert new node at root
    if (cmp < 0) {
      Node n = new Node(key);
      n.left = root.left;
      n.right = root;
      root.left = null;
      root = n;
    } else if (cmp > 0) { // Insert new node at root
      Node n = new Node(key);
      n.right = root.right;
      n.left = root;
      root.right = null;
      root = n;
    } else { // It was a duplicate key. Simply replace the value
      root.key = key;
    }

  }

  /***************************************************************************
   *  Splay tree deletion.
   ***************************************************************************/
  /* This splays the key, then does a slightly modified Hibbard deletion on
   * the root (if it is the node to be deleted; if it is not, the key was
   * not in the tree). The modification is that rather than swapping the
   * root (call it node A) with its successor, it's successor (call it Node B)
   * is moved to the root position by splaying for the deletion key in A's
   * right subtree. Finally, A's right child is made the new root's right
   * child.
   */
  public void remove(int key) {
    if (root == null) return; // empty tree

    root = splay(root, key);

    int cmp = Integer.compare(key, root.key);

    if (cmp == 0) {
      if (root.left == null) {
        root = root.right;
      }
      else {
        Node x = root.right;
        root = root.left;
        splay(root, key);
        root.right = x;
      }
    }

    // else: it wasn't in the tree to remove
  }


  /***************************************************************************
   * Splay tree function.
   * **********************************************************************/
  // splay key in the tree rooted at Node h. If a node with that key exists,
  //   it is splayed to the root of the tree. If it does not, the last node
  //   along the search path for the key is splayed to the root.
  private Node splay(Node h, int key) {
    if (h == null) return null;

    int cmp1 = Integer.compare(key, root.key);

    if (cmp1 < 0) {
      // key not in tree, so we're done
      if (h.left == null) {
        return h;
      }
      int cmp2 = Integer.compare(key, h.left.key);
      if (cmp2 < 0) {
        h.left.left = splay(h.left.left, key);
        h = rotateRight(h);
      }
      else if (cmp2 > 0) {
        h.left.right = splay(h.left.right, key);
        if (h.left.right != null)
          h.left = rotateLeft(h.left);
      }

      if (h.left == null) return h;
      else                return rotateRight(h);
    }

    else if (cmp1 > 0) {
      // key not in tree, so we're done
      if (h.right == null) {
        return h;
      }

      int cmp2 = Integer.compare(key, h.right.key);
      if (cmp2 < 0) {
        h.right.left  = splay(h.right.left, key);
        if (h.right.left != null)
          h.right = rotateRight(h.right);
      }
      else if (cmp2 > 0) {
        h.right.right = splay(h.right.right, key);
        h = rotateLeft(h);
      }

      if (h.right == null) return h;
      else                 return rotateLeft(h);
    }

    else return h;
  }


  /***************************************************************************
   *  Helper functions.
   ***************************************************************************/

  // height of tree (1-node tree has height 0)
  public int height() { return height(root); }

  private int height(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return -1;
    return 1 + Math.max(height(x.left), height(x.right));
  }


  public int size() {
    return size(root);
  }

  private int size(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return 0;
    x.size = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
    return x.size;
  }

  // right rotate
  private Node rotateRight(Node h) {
    Node x = h.left;
    h.left = x.right;
    x.right = h;
    return x;
  }

  // left rotate
  private Node rotateLeft(Node h) {
    Node x = h.right;
    h.right = x.left;
    x.left = h;
    return x;
  }



  static class InputReader {

    public BufferedReader reader;
    public StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 32768);
      tokenizer = null;
    }

    public String next() {
      while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        try {
          tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
      return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    public int nextInt() {
      return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    public long nextLong() {
      return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    public double nextDouble() {
      return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }

    public char[] nextCharArray() {
      return next().toCharArray();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
      try {
        String string = reader.readLine();
        if (string == null) {
          return false;
        }
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string);
        return tokenizer.hasMoreTokens();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public BigInteger nextBigInteger() {
      return new BigInteger(next());
    }

    public BigDecimal nextBigDecinal() {
      return new BigDecimal(next());
    }

    public void close() {
      try {
        reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("close err");
      }
      tokenizer = null;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to step through code with a debugger. We won't do it for you if you don't make the effort.

Comment: Thank you and I try some instances but all of them work without exception.